# Laravel PHP return array in a specific way

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I'm trying to return an array to json in laravel so i can build a chart on a view. The controller looks like this.

```
    //Paso 1. Buscar el gráfico asociado a este ID
    $chartset = Chart::findOrFail($chart);

    $q = $chartset->dataset()->first(); //Buscar la pregunta
    $Question = Question::find($q->labels); //Para usar los datos en el arreglo que regresa en JSON

    //Armando los Datos

    //Hace falta asignar el tipo de gráfico
    //Paso 2 Crear el Arreglo para devolver el chart data
    $ChartData = array(    //Arreglo con los parámetros del Chart
        "chart" => array( 
            "title" => $chartset->title, 
            "caption" => $Question->FullLabel, 
            "subcaption" => "February 2016", 
            "captionFontSize" => "24", 
            "paletteColors" => "#A2A5FC, #41CBE3, #EEDA54, #BB423F, #F35685", 
            "baseFont" => "Quicksand, sans-serif", 
            //more chart configuration options
         )
    ); 

    $ChartData["data"] = array(); //Arreglo donde iran los labels 

    //Paso 3, Iterar por cada uno de los datos en el chart

   foreach($chartset->dataset()->get() as $charts){ 
        $ans = Answer::where('AnswerId',$charts->data)  //Obtener Las respueestas
                     ->where('QuestionId',$charts->labels)
                     ->first();

        $responses = DB::table('responses') //Obtener los respondientes que contestaron con esa respuesta
                 ->join('questions', 'responses.QuestionId', '=', 'questions.QuestionId')
                 ->select('questions.FullLabel','responses.QuestionId',DB::raw('responses.Value as Label'),DB::raw('count(responses.Value) as Total'))
                 ->where('responses.QuestionId',$ans->QuestionId)
                 ->where('responses.Value',$ans->Label)
                 ->groupBy('questions.FullLabel','responses.Value','responses.QuestionId')
                 ->get();
      
        foreach($responses as $response){  //Llenar el arreglo con datos
            array_push($ChartData["data"], array( 
                "label" => $response->Label, 
                "value" => $response->Total 
            )); 
        }

   }

    return response()->json($ChartData);
```

And the returned value looks like this

```
{
"chart": {
 "title": "Dashboard Test",
 "caption": "Q062. Ya que vio el anuncio, ¿cómo se siente sobre TABCIN?",
 "subcaption": "February 2016",
 "captionFontSize": "24",
 "paletteColors": "#A2A5FC, #41CBE3, #EEDA54, #BB423F, #F35685",
 "baseFont": "Quicksand, sans-serif"
 },
"data": [
  {
   "label": "-3 La odio",
   "value": 5
  },
  {
   "label": "+3 La amo",
   "value": 127
  },
  {
   "label": "-1",
   "value": 15
  },
  {
   "label": "-2",
   "value": 6
  },
  {
   "label": "0 Neutral",
   "value": 214
  },
  {
   "label": "+2",
   "value": 150
  },
  {
   "label": "+1",
   "value": 85
  }
 ]
}
```

What I want is the returned data to look like this.

```
{
"chart": {
 "title": "Dashboard Test",
 "caption": "Q062. Ya que vio el anuncio, ¿cómo se siente sobre TABCIN?",
 "subcaption": "February 2016",
 "captionFontSize": "24",
 "paletteColors": "#A2A5FC, #41CBE3, #EEDA54, #BB423F, #F35685",
 "baseFont": "Quicksand, sans-serif"
 },
"data": [
  {
   "label": ["-3 La odio","+3 La amo","-1","-2","0 Neutral","+2","+1",],
   "value": [5,127,15,6,214,150,86],
  },
 ]
}
```

Is there any way to return the label and value data like that?.

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the way you build the data array like this

```
foreach($responses as $response){  //Llenar el arreglo con datos
    $ChartData["data"]['label'][] = $response->Label;
    $ChartData["data"]['value'][] = $response->Total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. This is what i was looking for. I appreciate your help.